# Directory API Java users.list permissions

Tags: java, permissions, google-admin-sdk, google-directory-api

please, anyone could tell me which permissions I should grant a user or service account to be able to access "Admin SDK Directory API" and use users.list method?
Thanks in advance.
Stefano

Comment: If [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74099446/17926478) answered your question, please click the accept button on the left (check icon). By doing so, other people in the community, who may have the same concern as you, will know that theirs can be resolved. If the accept button is unavailable to you, feel free to tell me. [How to accept answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on what you need, you can assign a Super Admin role and it will have access to all features in the Admin console and Admin SDK or in this case if you only want the user to be able to use the method [users.list](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/reference/rest/v1/users/list) then you can [create a custom role](https://support.google.com/a/answer/2406043?topic=2785005&ctx=topic) and grant the [privileges](https://support.google.com/a/answer/1219251?#zippy=%2Cadmin-api) you need. For example you can assign the  `Users > Read` privilege and the user should be able to use this method.

**References:**

[Directory API: Prerequisites](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/prerequisites)

Comment: Hi Lorena, I have asked to my admin to grant permission to the service account, but it doesn't work. I have read in some docs that It can take up to 24 hours for new roles to take effect, but the 24 hourse already passed...

Comment: @Stefano what exactly are you trying to do with the service account? Do you get any errors? Please share more details so I can help in a better way.

Comment: Hi Lorena, it works now! Really, the cloud took days (so more than 24 hours) before the new authorization was acquired by the service account